# What is align in memory sections of an object file?

Tags: c, assembly, elf, memory-alignment, objdump

I was using objdump here, and using the -x flag, I saw that the sections were with some 2 ** 0. What would somebody be? Has any practical effect on this align

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char *x = "section"; // .rodata algn 2**0 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why was this tagged NASM?  I'm not aware of any C compilers that compile into NASM syntax.

Comment: Sorry, mate, I really do not think you have. I checked only to have more visibility, in case someone program in assembly for the nasm monator, but anyway, I will remove.

Comment: Anyway, `alignof(char) == 1` and compilers don't choose to give extra alignment for string literals.  So you get no required alignment (`2` to the power `0` = `1` ) for alignment of that ELF section.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I think I'll have to study about memory alignment a bit more